# c++ switch - not evaluating and showing "Condition is always true"

Tags: c++, switch-statement, logical-or

I was experimenting whether I can use "logical or" inside case clause for a switch statement. I tried this way for the first case and the system skipped it all together when I gave input as "A" or "a" in both the cases.

```
# include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main () {
  /* prg. checks if the input is an vowel */

  char ch;
  cout << "please input a word to check if it is vowel or not" << endl;
  cin >> ch;

  switch (ch) {
      case ('A'|| 'a') :
          cout << "it is vowel" << endl;
          break;

      case 'E':
          cout << "it is vowel" << endl;
          break;

      case 'I':
          cout << "it is vowel" << endl;
          break;

      case 'O':
          cout << "it is vowel" << endl;
          break;

      case 'U':
          cout << "it is vowel" << endl;
          break;

      default:
          cout << "it is not a vowel" << endl;
          break;


  }
```

is there a proper way to use or inside the case clause ?

Thank you for the help.

Comment: You need to learn what expressions are.

Comment: try to to create two different cases one for 'A' and one for 'a'. This will work

Comment: `'A'|| 'a'` evaluates to 1. The case is equal to `case 1`.

Comment: You can have more than one `case` for a given block: `case 'A': case 'a': <code> break;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `case ('A'|| 'a')` should be written as:

```cpp
switch (ch) {
case 'A':
case 'a':
    cout << "it is vowel" << endl;
    break;
// ...
```

If it matches on `'A'` it will fall through to the next `case` (unless there's a `break` in between).

In this case, you may want to combine *all* vowles:

```
switch (ch) {
case 'A':
case 'a':
case 'E':
case 'e':
//... all of them ...
    std::cout << "it is vowel\n";
    break;
// ...
```

Note that some compilers will issue a warning for fall through `case`s with statements in them (which is not the case above). Since C++17, if you use fall through cases, you can use the [`fallthrough`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/fallthrough) attribute to silence such warnings where you actually want a fall through.

Comment: Usually compilers issue the fallthrough warning only when there is code between the 2 `case`s, like `case 'A': cout << "Uppercase "; case 'a': cout << "vowel\n"; break;`.

Comment: Compilers will not generate fallthrough warnings when the case is empty, like here in `case 'A'`. Because it is so common to have several cases grouped together like in this example. But if there is at least one statement in the case without a final `break` or `return`, this is very suspicious and `[[fallthrough]];` is highly recommended.

Comment: You are both correct. I changed the wording slightly.